# Map making resources for SC2

Tags: starcraft-2, galaxy-editor

Where can I find *good* resources for making maps in SC2?

Are there any good tutorials out there on the map editing tools, as I always find the experience of making custom content

What goes into the design of a good map?

Comment: Recommendation questions are off-topic as per our [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq), and as such your question will be closed.

Comment: That said, the question of 'What goes into the design of a good map' could be *very* interesting -  this question may be worth rewriting. It should be noted however, that such a question is better asked on GameDev in general.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I thought about that as well, but I'm concerned that question would be too subjective.

Comment: @Wipqozn There are a number of very important and objective criteria on what makes a map good for different things. It needs clarification sure, but there are, for example, very well defined principles for making competitive 1v1 multiplayer maps.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz  A good point, but I think the question would need to be fleshed out beyond "Good map" for it to work (in whic case I think it would be a really good question)

Answer (score 2):

There are very few "good resources" on using the Galaxy Editor, and I have yet to come across a simple and straight forward hands on tutorial for it. A few sites have been helpful in the past to me:

[SC2 Mapster](http://www.sc2mapster.com/) has a few bits of documentation, as well as a reference on built-in functions of the Galaxy language. I found this rather useful.

[IronManSC](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=285931) has been doing casts on the topic, and I've found them very helpful as well, although they are not "beginner level".

You should also look at The Hive Workshop, a Warcraft 3 modding community. Many of their members also do SC2 mods, so you will find a lot of useful information on the forums. Just google for them, SXC won't let me post more than 2 links for being a newbie.

There is no official documentation, as far as I know, and Blizzard doesn't officially support the Galaxy Editor. Maybe things will change when Heart of the Swarm comes out, as it carries a lot of updates to the editor, and even some new tools.